# How to do a startsWith and then Contains Search using Lucene.NET 3.0?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, contains, startswith

What is the best way to search and Index in Lucene.NET 3.0 so that the results come out ordered in the following way:

1. Results that start with the full query text (as a single word) e.g. "Bar Acme"
2. Results that start with the search term as a word fragment e.g. "Bart Simpson"
3. Results that contain the query text as a full word e.g. "National Bar Association"
4. Results that contain the query text as a fragment e.g. "United Bartenders Inc"

Example: Searching for *Bar*

Ordered Results:

1. Bar Acme
2. Bar Lunar
3. Bart Simpson
4. National Bar Association
5. International Bartenders Association

Answer (score 1):

Lucene doesn't generally support searching/scoring based on position within a field.  It would be possible to support it if you prefix every fields with some known fieldstart delimiter, or something.  I don't really think it makes sense, in the lens of a full text search where position within the text field isn't relevant (ie. if I were searching for Bar in a document, I would likely be rather annoyed if "Bart Simpson" were returned before "national bar association")

Apart from that though, a simple prefix search handles everything else.  So if you simply add your start of word token, you can search for the modified term with a higher boost prefix query than the original, and then you should have precisely what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with linq. Make lucene search with hit count Int32.MaxValue. Loop the results of ScoreDocs and store it in collection Searchresults.

**sample code:**

```
Searchresults = (from scoreDoc in results.ScoreDocs select (new SearchResults { suggestion = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc).Get("suggestion") })).OrderBy(x => x.suggestion).ToList();

Searchresultsstartswith = Searchresults.Where(x => x.suggestion.ToLower().StartsWith(searchStringLinq.ToLower())).Take(10).ToList();

if (SearchresultsStartswith.Count > 0)
    return SearchresultsStartswith.ToList();
else
    return Searchresults.Take(10).ToList();
```